# How does taking intersections and irreducible components affect the degree?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $Z_1,\dotsc,Z_J$ be affine subvarieties of $\mathbf{A}^n$ of dimension $\leq d$ and degree $\leq D$. (We may assume the convention that the degree of reducible variety is the sum of the degrees of its components, but, alternatively, you may just assume that $Z_1,\dotsc,Z_J$ are all irreducible.) It is not hard to show that $Z=\bigcap_{j=1}^J Z_j$ is a variety of degree $\leq D^{d+1}$. (Hint: Bézout and induction.)

Now define $[V]$ as the devil's favorite irreducible component. Let $Z'$ be an expression of the form
$$[\dotsc[[[Z_1\cap Z_2]\cap [Z_3\cap Z_4] \cap Z_5]\dotsc Z_J],$$
that is, an expression $Z_1\cap Z_2\cap \dotsc Z_J$ in which the devil's brackets have been put in whichever order.

Can we bound $\deg(Z')$ by $D^{d+1}$? Can we give any sort of similar, somewhat weaker bound?

EDIT: see the related question [When is a pair of space curves that intersect (plenty) a complete intersection?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383589/when-is-a-pair-of-space-curves-that-intersect-plenty-a-complete-intersection?noredirect=1#comment976422_383589)

Comment: In order to bound the degree of $Z'$ by $D^{d+1}$, can't you apply again Bézout as before? At any rate, it seems to me that in general you cannot do better than this, just take an irreducible complete intersection of two hypersurfaces.

Comment: I like the expression "the devil's favorite". I don't think I have come across it before.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Well, you have to use Bézout, but I don't see how to carry out the induction efficiently enough, in general. In the special case $[[\dotsc [[Z_1\cap Z_2]\cap Z_3]\cap \dotsc]]$, it is easy: at every step, either the dimension goes down by $1$ or nothing changes. And yes, of course $D^{d+1}$ would be optimal.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. No, I am not assuming the $Z_j$ are hypersurfaces initially.

Comment: (@WillSawin Do you mean I *can* assume the Z_ j are hypersurfaces initially (perhaps by a projection)? If so, how would that help?)

Comment: See the related question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383589/when-is-a-pair-of-space-curves-that-intersect-plenty-a-complete-intersection?noredirect=1#comment976141_383589 . If two curves as described in that equation, then (as was pointed out to me by A. Mellit elsewhere) the first question here has to be answered in the negative, even for $d=2$: we would have an example with $\deg(Z') \gg D^4$.

Answer (score 1):

Recording a similar but (much) weaker bound.  Start with the parse tree of the expression, a rooted binary tree where every leaf is one of the Z_j and every internal vertex corresponds to an intersection. Next, if an intersection equals one of the inputs prune the irrelevant branch from the tree, and if a vertex has exactly one child identify the two.  Since the dimension has to go down at every non-trivial intersection (we intersect irreducible components) the pruned tree has depth at most $d+1$ hence at most $2^d$ leaves.  Induction up the tree also gives the bound $D^{2^d}$ on the degree.

Comment: Thanks. The bound $\leq D^{d+1}$ does in fact seem to be correct for $d=2$ (and of course for $d=1$ and $d=0$). The argument is not long.

Comment: @HAHelfgott We can assume the root has dimension $\geq 1$ because $0$-dimensional  irreducible varieties have degree $1$. I think this already improves this to $D^{ 2^{d-1}}$, so you will need to look further to distinguish the bounds (but I should be careful after misreading the question).

Comment: @WillSawin Well, there are two valid ways of reading the question: $J-1$ brackets, or brackets wherever you want but not necessarily at every possible place (and so $\leq J-1$ brackets).